# Google Plus circle and email

Tags: google, google-plus

I had a Google Plus circle with one person in it.  I understand that an outsider can see on my profile who is in the circle, but can this outsider see emails, chats, hangouts, etc. too?

Answer (score 1):

> but can this outsider see emails, chats, hangouts, etc. too?

No, they can see only your public posts

Comment: And while they might be able to see you have a person Circled, they can't see what Circle you put them in.